# How to markup ascii-art tables automatically?

Tags: markup

I have a plain text file with tables:

http://uucode.com/tmp/20110913/vim-index.txt 
(or type ":help index" in vim)

I want to convert the table into a computer-friendly form. For example, into HTML or into Excel.

Any suggestion how to make it automatically? Maybe some lightweight markup tool can recognize such tables? Or probably there are some research papers with useful algorithms?

Answer (score 1):

The plugin "vimwiki : Personal Wiki for Vim" ( http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2226 ) defines a table syntax for its wiki pages:

```
 | Year | Temperature (low) | Temperature (high) |
 |------+-------------------+--------------------|
 | 1900 | -10               | 25                 |
 | 1910 | -15               | 30                 |
 | 1920 | -10               | 32                 |
 | 1930 | _N/A_             | _N/A_              |
 | 1940 | -2                | 40                 |
>

In HTML the following part >
 | Year | Temperature (low) | Temperature (high) |
 |------+-------------------+--------------------|
>
is higlighted as a table header.
```

And it provides a command to convert from text to html:

```
*:Vimwiki2HTML*
    Convert current wiki page to HTML.
```

Maybe you could use some regular expressions to convert your tables to this format, and then use this plugin to convert it to HTML.